# PHP array loop for in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have some array to go through foreach. Inside, I need to generate an array of quantity.

It still brings me back in both 0-5.

The output should look like this:

[image: Output]

```
$a = array(['id' => 1,'quantity' => 5,'input' => 'one'],
            ['id' => 2,'quantity' => 4,'input' => 'two'] );
foreach ($a as $b) {
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $b['quantity']; $x++) {
            $count[$x] = $x;
        }
        dump($b['quantity']);
        dump($count);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's hard to tell what you want to achieve, but I think your current described problem is, that you are overwriting the same array in your second loop and so it still contains 5 elements from the first loop.

Add this at the top of your `foreach`:

```
foreach ($a as $b) {
    $count = [];
    ...
```

This will reset the $count array on every iteration. This might bring new problems, but that's not easy to tell by the supplied information..

Comment: Thx. It's very simple. xD